# Get combinations of elements of a specific length

Tags: python, list, combinations

Edit:
This is not a exact duplicate of [How to get all possible combinations of a list’s elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/python-code-to-pick-out-all-possible-combinations-from-a-list)

This topic is about finding unique combinations while the other topic is about finding ALL combinations.

If I have a python list:

```
 L = [1,2,3,4]
```

what's the best way to get all the possible *unique combinations* of 3 elements from the list like below:

```
["1,2,3", "1,2,4", "2,3,4", "3,4,1"]
```

The order of the elements in the combinations doesn't matter. For example, `"1,2,3"` and `"3,2,1"` will be considered the same combination.

I can probably write a few loops to do this but I think there might be a one-liner which can do the same.

Comment: This question should not originally have been closed as a duplicate in the way that it was, or at least it should have been reopened. However, it *has* been asked more than once on Stack Overflow. I have re-linked it as a different duplicate, because that question got higher-quality answers.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You need [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> L = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> [",".join(map(str, comb)) for comb in combinations(L, 3)]
['1,2,3', '1,2,4', '1,3,4', '2,3,4']
```

Comment: Interestingly, this does give you unique combinations based on positions in the iterable, not based on values, as explained in the docs, see e.g.:
from itertools import combinations
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
[",".join(map(str, comb)) for comb in combinations(L, 3)]