# Python (large) lists and unique combinations: smartest way to do them

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, combinations, ram

I just read the page over here: [Get unique combinations of elements from a python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18201690/get-unique-combinations-of-elements-from-a-python-list)

The solution approved works...

... **But** it works only with "*small*" lists (100 elements, for example).

I have a "big" list of strings (**1 million of elements**) and i get the infamous `"MemoryError"` exception.

What is the best way to get unique combos on very large lists?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't. This is a bad idea.

Comment: What is the size of the combinations? Very quickly you'll have more data than you could hope to process

Comment: The size of combinations is "2"

Comment: Depending on how many of your 1M elements are indeed unique, you might be able to simply `uniques = tuple(set(elements))` and get the combinations of the elements  in `uniques`?

Comment: Thanks, this worked.

Comment: 1,000,000 choose 2 is 499,999,500,000, or just under 500 trillion.  Depending on what they are and your computer, you might be able to do it.

Comment: How many unique strings are in your list of a million strings? If you have lots of duplicate strings, then it _may_ be practical to build a list of all the pairs, but even then it's probably better to create an iterator, and process the pairs as they're produced. If all million strings are unique, then I doubt you have the RAM to hold a trillion pairs of strings (or half a trillion if you don't want both (a, b) and (b,a)).

Comment: @samcraig how can there be more than 1mil x 1 mil?

Comment: @roganjosh 499,999,500,000 is less than 1,000,000 squared.

Comment: @samcraig aha, I think we're at a language barrier, 1mil x 1mil is called a trillion in UK so 500 trillion is significantly more. I didn't count the digits.

Answer (score 0):

Per [inspectorG4dget's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45309708/python-large-lists-and-unique-combinations-smartest-way-to-do-them#comment77581571_45309708) and the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18201716/2000793), if a large number of values in your initial list are duplicated, filter them out through a `set` first, then find your combos.

```
from itertools import combinations

elements = [gigantic list]

uniques = tuple(set(elements))
combos = [','.join(str(thing) for thing in combo) for combo in combinations(uniques, 2)]
```