# Python - Printing multiple arrays of randomly sampled elements from an original array

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have an original array in python : *t_array*

```
t_array=(['META' , 'AAPL' , 'AMZN' , 'NFLX' , 'GOOG' ])

sample = random.sample (t_array, 3)

print=( 'sample')
```

and got this :

`['AAPL', 'AMZN', 'META']`

Now when I run the `(1)` code again the sample refreshes to a new triple element array like the following :

`['AMZN', 'META', 'NFLX']` or so

I wish to **get all possible combinations** without replacement from the original array **t_array** **and print them** at once in a **dataframe** format or **series** format so I can refer to them by index in my further code

**How do I code that in python?**

**machine**: currently using jupyter notebook on mac osx

Comment: Welcome to SO! +1 for sharing the code, however, for easier reading, I would suggest pulling in all the relevant code in one code block and update your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get unique combinations of elements from a python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18201690/get-unique-combinations-of-elements-from-a-python-list)

Comment: Also, you are using a [built-in keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) as a variable i.e. `print = ('sample')`. This would create a problem later in the code when you want to actually print something (e.g. try `print(sample)` after `print = ('sample')`). I hope this was a typo and not intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) function from itertools.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(combinations(t_array, 3))
```

#### Code:

```
from itertools import combinations
import pandas as pd

t_array=(['META' , 'AAPL' , 'AMZN' , 'NFLX' , 'GOOG' ])

df = pd.DataFrame(combinations(t_array, 3))

print(df)
```

#### Output:

```
      0     1     2
0  META  AAPL  AMZN
1  META  AAPL  NFLX
2  META  AAPL  GOOG
3  META  AMZN  NFLX
4  META  AMZN  GOOG
5  META  NFLX  GOOG
6  AAPL  AMZN  NFLX
7  AAPL  AMZN  GOOG
8  AAPL  NFLX  GOOG
9  AMZN  NFLX  GOOG
```